# How can I set the value of data-id in php to a variable?

Tags: php, html

The following code works

```
echo '<td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="30" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete22</a></td>';
```

But the following code does not work

```
echo '<td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id=$aa   data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete22</a></td>';
```

Thanks friends

Comment: whats the error? can u please attach a screenshot

Comment: <htmlElement data-id="<?= $aa ?>">Text</htmlElement>